# jquery cookie variable is not getting updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

my code is as follows

on select of jquery datepicker I am calling the following code

```
$.removeCookie("log_dt"); 
$.cookie("log_dt", $(this).val());
alert($.cookie("log_dt"));
```

which should remove the previously set cookie value and puts the new value 
 but it does not work how can I fix it, what m I going wrong

Answer (score 0):

For putting new value you don't need to remove cookie just do as below to reset value. Your code is looking fine so please check **$(this).val()**.

```
$.cookie("log_dt", "New Value");
```

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wMN7G/402/)

Comment: what you are getting in $(this).val() ?

Comment: m getting 2016-10-14

Comment: it was bcs of the path in which the cookie is being saved i mentioned path in the remove cookie and it worked . 3 cookie variables were created for the site with different path n same name dont know how. Thanks for attempting

Answer (score 0):

it was because of the path in which the cookie was being saved, the wrong cookie was getting replaced

```
 $.removeCookie("log_dt",{path: '/path', domain: domain}); this worked
```